# Angular2 - Not all child components are destroyed when routing to a new page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Not all child components are destroyed properly when routing to a new page. At this stage i'm not sure if its a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

Problem:

Basically I have 2 routes called PageOne & PageTwo.

PageOne is a component which renders a child component (TestComponent) 3 times via an ngFor loop.

```
<test-component  *ngFor="let item of items;"></test-component>
```

If I route to PageTwo I would expect that all 3 child components be destroyed. If you see the instructions to reproduce on my plunker you will see that only 2 of the 3 child components are destroyed.

Here is a Plunker that reproduces the issue.
http://embed.plnkr.co/uor231/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue which seems to be fixed already (but no version containing the fix is published yet) https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8458

Comment: I remembered seeing it recently, that usually makes it easier to find :)